# Xml string to java object using Freemarker Template

Tags: freemarker

I want to convert xml string (for eg. abc@gmail.com1111111111) into java object (eg. Test.java having properties same as that are in xml string) using freemarker template.
Can any one help me on this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your question really related to Freemarker, or is it rather (general) Java related?

Comment: Actually i have used freemarker to convert object to xml but now i want it in reverse so that's why i need to use freemarker. Gone through the docs also but didn't find any thing related.

Comment: Got the solution. First get InputSource from your xml string then parse it and get the NodeModel. Then get the NodeList. Finally, iterate through NodeList and get nodeName and textContent

Answer (score 0):

Use JAXB to work with XML in Java.

```
public static Test deserializeXMLString(String xmlString)
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
    Test t = (Test)unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    return t;
}
```